# Nothing happens after running any docker-compose command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

`docker-compose` stopped working (Hetzner VPS running Ubuntu 18.04).

My terminal looks like this:

```sh
user@hostname:~/$ docker-compose ps
^C^C^C^C^C
```

As you can see, Ctrl-C also does nothing.

Running `docker` commands works just fine. But anything `docker-compose` hangs. I can kill the `docker-compose` process manually but that's about it.

What I've tried:

- Download a fresh docker-compose to a fresh virtualenv and run that. Same result.
- Upgrade the whole system
- Reboot

I'm stuck, I don't know where else to look for how to tackle this problem. Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Edit1:

It doesn't matter what folder I'm in, or whether I add a command (like) `ps`, or whether I use sudo or not. Behaviour is the same everywhere.

Comment: Seems you are in the home folder `~`, isn't you should run this command in a folder with `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: Folder doesn't matter. I've updated the question.

Comment: I suggest you use `strace` to debug it, like `strace docker-compose ps` to see where it hang.

Comment: solved it by throwing away everything in /var/lib/docker and reinstalling docker

Comment: possibly it was just really really, really slow also

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, the problem was solved by installing `haveged`. Somehow `docker-compose` depends on having a lot of entropy available, which was thus solved.

More details here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6678